# Completeness of solutions and the separation of variables method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The method of separation of variables is introduced in every textbook on mathematical physics.

A basic question is rarely addressed: does this method exhaust all the solutions?

Is there any fundamental theorem available for answering this question? At least for some kinds of equation?

Comment: Crosposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/167074/2451

Comment: Sometimes uniqueness can be shown separately (e.g. by the "energy method"). I think it would help if you have a particular PDE in mind.